# Pre cache folder and subfolder content

Tags: service-worker

Is there a way to precache all files in folder and its subfolders?

What i want to accomplish is something like this:

```
...
event.waitUntil(
      caches
        .open(version + 'fundamentals')
        .then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                "/",
                "/images/*"
...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JavaScript executing in the context of your service worker won't have any knowledge of your filesystem.

If you'd like to precache all of the files matching a specific wildcard pattern, you'll need to add some build-time tooling, when the code that's being executed has access to your filesystem. The build-time tool can then feed output into a service worker's JavaScript file, ideally via some templating system.

The [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/master/GettingStarted.md) tool can automate this process for you, including generating the service worker's JavaScript and keeping your caches up to date as static assets in your local filesystem change.

If you choose not to use a pre-packaged solution like `sw-precache`, make sure that you understand the service worker `install`/`activate` lifecycle events, and that you're properly versioning your static resources and caches.